# avrdude.exe: invalid file format ' ' in update specifier error after setting up AVR studio 6 external tools

Tags: arduino, avr, avrdude

I have set up avr studio 6 as an Arduino IDE with the help of the tutorial at: http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/#final

I added an external tool as described in the tutorial and used the following argument:

```
-CC:\Program Files (x86)\arduino-1.0.1\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P\\.\COM4 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i
```

When I try to flash the Arduino Uno board this results in the following error:

```
avrdude.exe: invalid file format '\Users\UserName\Documents\ElectronicsProjects\bt-controller\software\gamecontroller\snes-controller\Debug\snes-contro.' in update specifier
avrdude.exe: error parsing update operation 'flash:w:C:\Users\UserName\Documents\ElectronicsProjects\bt-controller\software\gamecontroller\snes-controller\Debug\snes-contro.'
```

I tried renaming one of the folders, since the very first time one of the names contained a space. However the problem continues to exist. Is there any setting that I should change in the argument?

Comment: Looks like i figured it out by moving the arduino-1.0.1 folder out of the Program Files and straight on the c: drive. Now the avrdude programs the board in a flash.

Answer (score 3):

I made the same, and after triggering "Tools\Send to Arduino UNO", it returned exactly the same error message.
I have just fixed it by installing the Arduino IDE in \C: , in a folder without spaces in the filename (actually I also had forgotten the right COM port number...).

The correct string seems to be:
-CC:\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -p atmega328p -c arduino -P COM6 -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i

The baud rate (-b 11500) may be different, and the file path must be the right one.
More, the program only sees he right file name (in my version) if I click on the Project name on the far left window prior to flash... otherwise it looks for a file main.hex, not finding it ...